# Is it possible to copy the monkey runner results to a excel file

Tags: monkeyrunner

I want the results to be in a excel sheet.
The results should be made as a report.
I am testing a android device and want the result.
monkeyrunner

Comment: text to  CSV to  EXCEL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the whole process you can try [xlwt](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966) podule to write Excel files from python.

If `monkeyrunner` gives you some problem importing python modules give [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) a try.

Additionally, ask yourself whether you need Excel at all when you can generate nice reports from python using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) or [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html).